# Does replacing repititve "if" block with a macro reduce code complexity in C++?

Tags: c++, optimization, code-complexity

I had a question. I need to refactor a part of my code to reduce complexity. I have multiple similar "if" constructs which repeats after every some random utility API call, based on which I need to rollback the transaction done or else continue. I was just wondering whether replacing the "if" construct would help me reducing the complexity. I know macro expands in the code and that is why I am not sure whether this approach would help me. I am fairly new at refactoring codes. If someone with an idea and knowledge on refactoring could suggest me some way, it would be really helpful. It is like replacing below code

```
retCode = certman_set_cmp_server_psk_refnum(ctx,(char*)domain.c_str(),NULL,NULL,0);
if (retCode != 0)
{
    if(startedTxn == true)
    {
        status = ldapInterface.rollback_transaction();
        if(0 != status)
        {
            clifwk_trace(session, "Rollback failed in internal transaction", CLIFWK_DEBUG);
            syslog(LOG_ERR, "Rollback failed in internal transaction");
            return CERTMAN_COMMIT_TRANSACTION_FAILED;
        }
        DEL_IF_NOT_NULL (ctx);
    }
    return retCode;
}
```

with `retCode = certman_set_cmp_server_ip_port(ctx,(char*)domain.c_str(),NULL,0);
    CHECK_ROLLBACK_TRANSACTION(session,ctx,ldapInterface,retCode,startedTxn);
    RETURN_IF_ERROR(retCode);`

Will this approach work for me to reduce the complexity ?

Comment: Why use a macro? It looks like you could get the job done with a function.

Comment: What do you return if `retcode == 0`?

Comment: Would the macro expands to different code? If not, why do you think the macro version would reduce complexity?

Comment: I have little experience with refactoring c++ code either, but I would completely agree with @user2357112. Usually macros decrease code readability, while using functions for recurrent statements increases readability and reduces complexity.

Answer (score 3):

Your complexity problem appears to be caused by too much C, too little C++. Adding *more* C in the form of macro's only makes it worse.

For instance, `DEL_IF_NOT_NULL (ctx);` is not one but two **three** flags. I assume it's a `if (ctx) delete ctx` construct. The first red flag is the `if` statement, which doesn't do anything. The second red flag is that you're using raw pointers, instead of relying on smart pointers. This would have also fixed the third red flag, and that's the failure to clean up in the `0!=status` error case.

Similar complexicy is caused by using `retcode` instead of exceptions.

This is how simple the code should  be:

```
std::unique_ptr<T> ctx = foo();
auto transaction = ldapInterface.get_transaction(); // will rollback unless committed
certman::set_cmp_server_psk_refnum(*ctx,domain,nullptr,nullptr,0);
transaction.commit();
```